# How to Get List of Classes where string Property is null or Empty string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, findall

I have a class called, `Header`, and within another Class, called `Home`, I create a `List<Header>`, called `HeaderList`, which works fine and gathers the List of Headers that are needed.  The `Header` class has a property called, `MobileImage` that I would like to get within another List where all `MobileImage` property `IsNullOrEmpty`, but this is returning an empty list all of the time with this code below:

```
List<Header> NonMobileHeaderList = Home.HeaderList.FindAll(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.MobileImage)).ToList();

if (NonMobileHeaderList.Count > 0)
{
    Response.Write("There are Images for Non-Mobile Browsers.");
}
else
{
   Response.Write("There are no Images for Non-Mobile Browsers.")
}
```

My understanding is that `FindAll` should return all of the Elements in a List based on a predicate.  Why is this not working?  If I do:

`List<Header> AllHeaders = Home.HeaderList;`

All Headers contain a List of Headers correctly.  Do I have to loop through all headers in order to get the ones I need based on property value?  Seriously?  I thought `FindAll` was supposed to do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, when you debug there are Header items where the value of MobileImage is not null or empty?

Comment: Currently, all `MobileImage` string properties should be empty right now.

Comment: All Header Items have `MobileImage = string.Empty`, so the List should return them all, instead it returns none of them.

Comment: Seems more a Page Lifecycle issue than FindAll. The statement is correct, besides you won't need the .ToList as FindAll should already return a new List<T> instance.

Comment: Ok, thanks, got it worked out, you were right, a Lifecycle issue it was!

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the `.ToList()` since [`FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an explicit `List<T>`.

Comment: @dbc - Thanks, I removed the `.ToList()` as well.  You guys rock! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems more a Page Lifecycle issue than `FindAll`. The statement is **correct**, besides you won't need the `.ToList()` as FindAll should already return a new `List<T>` instance.

Comment: Cheers, Peter, I initialized a new `List<Header>` list at the top of the document, and assigned it to that, and bam, working perfect.